# Common Lisp: uiop:run-program outputs but uiop:launch-program does not

Tags: common-lisp, uiop

Basically,

```lisp
(uiop:run-program "echo hello" :output *standard-output*)
```

outputs `hello`, while none of

```lisp
(uiop:launch-program "echo hello" :output *standard-output*)
(uiop:launch-program "echo hello" :output #.*standard-output*)
(uiop:launch-program "echo hello" :output :interactive)
```

output anything; however, if I do run

```lisp
(uiop:run-program "echo hello" :output *standard-output*)
```

after them, I do get `hello` 4 times indicating `echo hello` did run. Why is this the case? (`(force-output)` doesn't change anything either.)

Edit: I am using SBCL with SLIME. And as suggested in the comments, this works as-expected (I get the output) on running it from the terminal.

Comment: It seems to happen in Emacs+Slime, calling sbcl from a terminal and executing launch-program with standard-output works over here.

Comment: Probably a good idea to mention which Lisp you use and how you run it (terminal, slime, something else, ...). When you post a question, it often would be useful to have code and the necessary information, which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, I am using SBCL with SLIME.

Comment: @coredump, yup, I can confirm that behaviour - it works from the terminal. So, is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe it's a feature of LAUNCH-PROGRAM? Remember that this is non-trivial: we use SBCL and its output stream is 'connected' to GNU Emacs&SLIME. We then call a shell command which does output, which then gets to -> SBCL -> GNU Emacs&SLIME...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the implementations of `run-program` and `launch-program`, you see that the former (in this case…) does a `wait-process`.

If you issue a `uiop:wait-process` on the process-info returned by `launch-program`, your output appears.

I guess that it is a kind of race condition where swank or slime doesn't get to pick up the output before it does something else.  I think that this is inherent in the *asynchronous* behaviour of `launch-program`.

I think that the clearest way to get the output is to specify `:output :stream` and then use the stream available from calling `process-info-output` on the return value of `launch-program`.

Comment: My use case turns out to be actually asynchronous, so calling `uiop:wait-process` will not help. I am using `:output :stream` (and reading the output from a separate thread). Thank you for the help!